# Get specific files only based on their name from given directory path

Tags: powershell

What I have tried so far:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "D:\sdf\fgh\ls\" -filter ABC.json,DEF.json)
```

And what I get:

> ```
> The term 'DEF.json' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At C:\Users\M1046511\Documents\collection.ps1:1 char:96
> + ... \sdf\fgh\ls\" -filter ABC.json|DEF.json){
> +                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DEF.json.json:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

My Expectation:
Should search for given files in the folder path.
I do not want to give any pattern to search for file. Directly wants to give name of files.

Comment: Hello Ankita, would it be possible for you to actually form a question? You have your code and the exception, that is a nice start! But how about what you want to achieve and what your exact question is on this path?

Answer (score 1):

The `-Filter` parameter of Get-ChildItem only supports a single string/condition.
What you can do in this case is use the `-Include` parameter. This parameter does handle arrays, but in order for it to work you **must** also add the `-Recurse` parameter.
Something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\sdf\fgh\ls\" -Include "ABC.json","DEF.json" -Recurse
```

Another possibility would be to first filter all .json files and then use the `Where-Object` to get the exact two files you want.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\sdf\fgh\ls\" -Filter "*.json" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^ABC|DEF' }
```

Hope this helps